# Want a stored procedure for comma seperated string which is of a column (has 20000 rows ) in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table with 20000 rows, and a column that has comma-separated strings in it. I want split each of the comma-separated strings from each row and insert them into a temp table row by row without any duplicates. I want to create a stored procedure for this table with has table name and column as parameters to that stored procedure.

Here is the table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Campaign]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MISC] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Here is the data which has

```
insert into Campaign(MISC) 
values ('h101,h202,h506,h707,h112,h566'),
       ('h101,h102,h508,h113,h456,h678'),
       ('h110,h880,h432,h111,h102,h509,h213'),
       ('h456,h609,h432,h456,h678,h101,h807')
```

I have a the login for single string but I don't know how to deal with these 20000 rows of comma-separated strings in the given column - any help?

Comment: if you can chane your table structure then change it.and you can easily transform 20k data using below script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Cross Apply with a a Parse should do the trick

**Option 1 - With a UDF**

```
Select A.ID
      ,B.* 
  From Campaign A
  Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse-8K](A.Misc,',') B
```

**Option 2 - Without a UDF**

```
Select A.ID
      ,B.* 
  From Campaign A
  Cross Apply (
                Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                      ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.Misc,',','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
              ) B
```

**Both Return**

```
ID  RetSeq RetVal
1   1       h101
1   2       h202
1   3       h506
1   4       h707
1   5       h112
1   6       h566
2   1       h101
2   2       h102
2   3       h508
...
4   3       h432
4   4       h456
4   5       h678
4   6       h101
4   7       h807
```

**The UDF if Needed**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse-8K] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(25))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
           cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 a,cte1 b,cte1 c,cte1 d) A ),
           cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter)) = @Delimiter),
           cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By A.N)
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(Substring(@String, A.N, A.L)))
    From   cte4 A
);
--Orginal Source http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/
--Much faster than str-Parse, but limited to 8K
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('John||Cappelletti||was||here','||')
--Performance On a 5,000 random sample -8K 77.8ms, -1M 79ms (+1.16), -- 91.66ms (+13.8)
```

Comment: @BumbleBee Happy it helped

Comment: what i heard here is that xml split perform better than 8k split.https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: @KumarHarsh Actually the 8K split is faster, but not by much.  In the comments listed in the UDF, on a 5,000 row test the 8K was (on average) was 13.8ms faster

Comment: @KumarHarsh That said, I use use the XML version of the parse by default because there is no size limit and the performance is respectable

Comment: I am also lil confuse.did you read the comment below by the "8k split" author ?Can you conclude ?Also in normal scenario length of string can never be more than 100 or 200 and there can never be more than 5 or 10 comma seperated in single string.so we can further customise split string.In fact keep 2 split function.One for small string and one for big string.Am I right ?

Comment: @KumarHarsh Correct, However, if you are constantly splitting, you may want to re-think the data model.  I tend to split parameters from my web apps and such.