# Add rows to result set from comma delimited data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a select statement returning data in the following format- (from a bad database design)

```
ID  Numbers           
3   6,7,8
```

and I need to tweak it to return

```
ID  Number             
3   6    
3   7  
3   8
```

to fix it.  What's the best way to do this? I do not need a permanent function, I just need the result set from a select query to import into a new database.

thanks!

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server or perhaps Sybase? The answer will depend on the dbms used.

Comment: BTW, that last edit didn't do much good...

Comment: Not aware of a SQL Server 2015.  If 2016 take a peek at string_split()

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using SQL Server 2015, your best option is to write a UDF like so:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udfSplit]
    (
      @sInputList VARCHAR(8000) -- List of delimited items
      ,
      @sDelimiter VARCHAR(8000) = ',' -- delimiter that separates items
    )
RETURNS @List TABLE ( item VARCHAR(8000) )
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @sItem VARCHAR(8000);
        WHILE CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter, @sInputList, 0) <> 0
            BEGIN
                SELECT  @sItem = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList, 1,
                                                       CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,
                                                              @sInputList, 0)
                                                       - 1))) ,
                        @sInputList = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,
                                                            CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,
                                                              @sInputList, 0)
                                                            + LEN(@sDelimiter),
                                                            LEN(@sInputList))));

                IF LEN(@sItem) > 0
                    INSERT  INTO @List
                            SELECT  @sItem;
            END;

        IF LEN(@sInputList) > 0
            INSERT  INTO @List
                    SELECT  @sInputList; -- Put the last item in
        RETURN;
    END;
```

And use it like so:

```
SELECT  ID ,
        item
FROM    ( SELECT    3 AS ID ,
                    '6,7,8' AS Numbers
        ) x
        CROSS APPLY udfSplit(x.Numbers, ',');
```

Comment: Had a similar function but was AMAZED at the performance gains of Tally approach.  Even the XML approach was more performant than the LOOP

Comment: If interested, I demonstrate an in-line XML approach and a tally approach here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43082763/want-a-stored-procedure-for-comma-seperated-string-which-is-of-a-column-has-200/43082930#43082930

Comment: @Icarus - nifty function thank you. I need to pull ID and numbers from existing tables. I'm not having any luck inserting a from clause anywhere. Putting "from" inside the inner select clause results in multiple rows for each ID but still getting the delimited strings in numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @YourTable Table (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
    , Number VARCHAR(10)
)
INSERT INTO @YourTable
VALUES
    ('1,2,3')
    , ('4,5,6,7')
    , ('8,9')
    , ('10')

;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS ID 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID + 1 FROM CTE
    WHERE ID < 100
)   
SELECT
    x.ID
    , SUBSTRING(x.Number, t.ID, CHARINDEX(',', x.Number + ',', t.ID) - t.ID) AS Number
FROM @YourTable x
JOIN CTE t
    ON t.ID <= DATALENGTH(x.Number)+1
    AND SUBSTRING(',' + x.Number, t.ID, 1) = ','
ORDER BY ID, Number
```

More information can be found here: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/