# Get the last three values with in a delimited string using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I would like to extract only the last three values from a delimited string and generate a delimited substring with those three values. Could anyone suggest what is the best way to do this. I tried using STRING_SPLIT and was able to successfully split the string into multiple values but I am not sure how to proceed further. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

```
SELECT value FROM  STRING_SPLIT('CatalogTypeCode VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
        ,EventID INT NOT NULL
        ,ModelCode TINYINT NOT NULL
        ,YearID INT NOT NULL
        ,PerilSetCode INT NOT NULL

        ,GrossLoss FLOAT  NULL
        ,GrossSD FLOAT  NULL
        ,GrossMaxLoss FLOAT  NULL',',')
```

Output:

```
CatalogTypeCode VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL

EventID INT NOT NULL

ModelCode TINYINT NOT NULL

YearID INT NOT NULL

PerilSetCode INT NOT NULL


GrossLoss FLOAT  NULL

GrossSD FLOAT  NULL

GrossMaxLoss FLOAT  NULL
```

Expected Output :

```
'GrossLoss FLOAT  NULL,GrossSD FLOAT  NULL,GrossMaxLoss FLOAT  NULL'
```

Comment: Have a look at [`DelimitedSplit8k`](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/), which provides the ordinal position of each item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps another option using a little `XML` in concert with `reverse()` ... twice

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,SomeCol varchar(150))
Insert Into @YourTable values 
 (1,'Val1,Val2,Val3,Val4')
,(2,'Val1,Val2,Val3,Val4,Val5,Val6')
,(3,'Val1,Val2')
,(4,'Val1')
,(5,null)

Select A.ID
      ,LastThree = reverse(concat(Pos1,','+Pos2,','+Pos3))
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                 Select Pos1 = n.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')
                       ,Pos2 = n.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')
                       ,Pos3 = n.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
                  From  (Select cast('<x>' + replace(reverse(SomeCol),',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as n) X
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
ID  LastThree
1   Val2,Val3,Val4
2   Val4,Val5,Val6
3   Val1,Val2        -- Notice only 2 values
4   Val1             -- Notice only 1 value
5                    -- Notice value was null
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `split_string()` doesn't return the position of the values within the string.

This will work, assuming there are no duplicates among the lines:

```
SELECT string_agg(line, ',') within group (order by pos) as lines_3
FROM (SELECT TOP (3) s.line, CHARINDEX(line, lines) as pos
      FROM (VALUES ('CatalogTypeCode VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
            ,EventID INT NOT NULL
            ,ModelCode TINYINT NOT NULL
            ,YearID INT NOT NULL
            ,PerilSetCode INT NOT NULL

            ,GrossLoss FLOAT  NULL
            ,GrossSD FLOAT  NULL
            ,GrossMaxLoss FLOAT  NULL')
         ) v(lines) OUTER APPLY
         STRING_SPLIT(v.lines, ',') s(line)
      ORDER BY pos
     ) s
```

EDIT:

Oops, the above works on SQL Server 2017, but not 2016.  You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT (MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN line END) + ','
        MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 2 THEN line END) + ','
        MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 3 THEN line END)
       ) as lines_3
FROM (SELECT TOP (3) s.line,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CHARINDEX(line, lines)) as seqnum
      FROM (VALUES ('CatalogTypeCode VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
            ,EventID INT NOT NULL
            ,ModelCode TINYINT NOT NULL
            ,YearID INT NOT NULL
            ,PerilSetCode INT NOT NULL

            ,GrossLoss FLOAT  NULL
            ,GrossSD FLOAT  NULL
            ,GrossMaxLoss FLOAT  NULL')
         ) v(lines) OUTER APPLY
         STRING_SPLIT(v.lines, ',') s(line)
      ORDER BY pos
     ) s;
```

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near 'v'.

Comment: @Teja . . . That is only a missing paren.  I also fixed the problem with `string_agg()`.

Comment: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 2
'string_agg' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 195, Level 15, State 15, Line 14
'STRING_SPLIT' is not a recognized function name.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this table-valued function for years now. Works fine. After creating function call `select top 3 * from lma.dbo.split_test('a,b,c,d,e',',') order by id desc`

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
  @String VARCHAR(MAX),
  @Delimiter VARCHAR(10)
)       
RETURNS @Temptable TABLE (id int identity, items varchar(MAX))       
AS       
BEGIN   

DECLARE @Idx INT       
DECLARE @Slice VARCHAR(MAX)       
DECLARE @Delimiterlen INT=LEN(@Delimiter)
        --,@String VARCHAR(MAX)='N'
        --,@Delimiter VARCHAR(10)=';;'

IF (@String like '%' + @Delimiter + '%')
    BEGIN

        SELECT @Idx = 1       
            IF LEN(@String)<@Delimiterlen or @String is null  RETURN       

        WHILE @Idx!= 0       
        BEGIN       
            SET @Idx = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String)       
            IF @Idx!=0       
                SET @Slice = left(@String,@idx-1)       
            ELSE       
                SET @Slice = @String       

            IF(LEN(@Slice)>0)  
                INSERT INTO @Temptable(Items) values(@Slice)       

            --290913 : IF WE WANT TO USE DELIMETER LENGTH GREATER THAN 2
            IF LEN(@String) >= (@Idx -1 + @Delimiterlen)
                SET @String = RIGHT(@String,LEN(@String) - (@Idx-1+@Delimiterlen))       
            IF LEN(@String) = 0 BREAK
        END   
    END

ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @Temptable(Items) values(@String) 
    END


DELETE @Temptable WHERE items =''

RETURN       
END
```

Comment: I used a similar function as well.  However, I was amazed at the performance gains using the tally approach or even a close second would be the XML approach

Comment: @JohnCappelletti - I don't think there will be a direct way of doing what you want. My best guess is adding auto-id in your split function, order by on desc and select top 3.

Comment: Take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43082763/want-a-stored-procedure-for-comma-seperated-string-which-is-of-a-column-has-200/43082930#43082930  they both have a sequence number.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I will look into this procedure but take a look at the updated answer. This may solve your problem.

Comment: I'm sure your function works perfectly.  It is just that the LOOPs can be performance killers.   Just food for thought  :)

Comment: Definitely avoid loops when possible as @JohnCappelletti  suggested